# Convergence of an exponential-like series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I was looking for the limit of the summation $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{h^{2k}}{k! k!}.$$ Thanks!

Comment: This is the modified Bessel function of the first kind with parameters $0$ and $2h$. (It is convergent, bounded by $e^{2|h|}$ from above

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's the modified Bessel function of the first kind $$I_{0}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{k}}{\left(k!\right)^{2}}
 $$ hence your series is $$\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{x^{2k}}{\left(k!\right)^{2}}=I_{0}\left(2x\right).$$ In general we have, for a real number $\nu$ $$I_{\nu}\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{\nu}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{k}}{k!\Gamma\left(\nu+k+1\right)}.
 $$